# Aiflow: how to delete file on SFTP using Apache Ariflow operator?

Tags: airflow, sftp, operator-keyword

Is there any way to delete specific file on SFTP server using Apache Airflow Operator.
I checked SFTPOperator but it support only put/get operations. If not how I can create my own custom operator and other option will be FTPHook.

```
delete_old_span_to_ftp = SFTPOperator(
    task_id = "delete_old_span_to_ftp",
    ssh_conn_id = 'nseix',
    remote_filepath='remote/path/.{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=None, key="del_td") 
    }}.i01_1.spn',
    operation="del",
    create_intermediate_dirs=True,
    dag=dag )
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can implement a funtion in SFTP to delete a file or directory using [this](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.remove) function made available on SFTPClient (paramiko) which can be fetched using `get_conn()` ([here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/79eac7687cf7c6bcaa4df2b8735efaad79a7fee2/airflow/providers/sftp/hooks/sftp.py#L120)) and then you can add another operation maybe `del` like `get` and call the above function that was created. It would be great if u can contribute back once done. Best of luck!

In case of FTP, you can do the same thing but on `FTP` (ftplib) calling [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.delete) function on `del` operation.

Hope this helps.